# How to create a 2D matrix with its names of rows and columns indexed in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I want to create a 2D- list or array that can be indexed with its row names and column names. Here's what this list, say A,  looks like :

```
Dates    Col1     Col2
2/1       x1       y1
2/2       x2       y2
2/3       x3       y3
```

This list can be accessed this way:

```
A['Col1'] = [x1, x2, x3]

A['2/1'] = [x1, y1]

A['2/1']['Col1'] = x1
```

Can this be achieved ? If so, how ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at `pandas` library, it was made for that!

Comment: Thanks @heltonbiker !

Comment: Want to set the above answer as correct one with reference to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. However not found any mark beside this this answer ...

Comment: I have edited my answer so that it elaborates on Pandas. Thanks for  your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library called [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).

With Pandas, you have a stack of columns, much like a spreadsheet, where each column has its label.

Besides that, there is a dedicated column containing indices, and those can also be used as (sort of) labels.

The operation you want to perform, that is, *selection* of items from a row, column, or combination of both, is called [indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html), or sometimes slicing.